# Regex - Capturing group with Alteration vs. Character classes

Tags: regex

I am working on the [problem 6 on regexone.com](http://regexone.com/example/5) and I am not able to understand how grouping works with 'alteration'.

This is the test string:

```
                The quick brown fox...
```

The task is to capture `The quick brown fox...` without the extra whitespace which can be done with `^\s*([\w\s.]*)\s*$`.

But `^\s*(\w|\s|\.)*\s*$` captures a group `'.'` ([27-28]) **Why?** As a result, `^\s*((\w|\s|\.)*)\s*$` captures two groups - `The quick brown fox...` [6-28] and `'.'` ([27-28]).

How does grouping work? What are the differences in working with alteration and character classes besides that character classes match by characters whereas alteration matches by words (my basic understanding)?

P.S.: How should I search for documentation like info on such problems when I don't even know what are they called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `^\s*(\w|\s|\.)*\s*$` captures a group '.' ([27-28]) Why?

The reason is that *capturing groups* store the text they match in a kind of a buffer or stack. The `*` quantifier makes the regex engine repeat capturing unlimited times and writes to that buffer each alphanumeric, or whitespace, or dot, each time **rewriting the value in the buffer**.

The `^\s*((?:\w|\s|\.)*)\s*$` has 2 capturing groups, thus it captures your whole text into Group 1 (wih the outer `(...)`), and the second capturing group is the one that stores the characters from the alternation matched one by one with only the last symbol remaining in the 2nd buffer.

The solution would be using a non-capturing group for alternations and a capturuing group for all the found submatches: `^\s*((?:\w|\s|\.)*)\s*$`.

Mind it is very inefficient! Use character classes wherever possible (i.e. `([\w\s.]*)`).

Comment: How is this process different for character class matching, I mean [abc]* vs (a|b|c)*?

Comment: When you have a character class, it gets compiled and checked against in 1 pass. When you have alternations, the engine adds an additional layer of backtracking, that complicates the task and makes the code exectute much slower. Compare the debug info for [`[abc]*`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ4tF1/1) and [`(a|b|c)*`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ4tF1/2) - 3 vs. 15 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Each capture group captures the string that matched that group. `((\w|\s|\.)*)` matches `The quick...`, so it sets the captured string correctly. But `(\w|\s|\.)` matches many times, once for each character; the captured string is then the last match, which is the `.` at the end of the text.